# Ruby: Check is one variable is of type conditional

Tags: ruby

In JS, I might do something like this..

```
# Very JS looking Ruby code
a = 1
b = 'e'
c = nil

if (a || b || c).is_a? String
    puts 'hi'
end
```

This doesn't work.

Is there way (without individual if/thens, to do something similar in Ruby?

Comment: I won't give this as an answer, as it has the disadvantage of creating a temporary array, but one could write, `[1,'e',nil].grep(String).any?  #=> true; [1,[2],nil].grep(String).any? #=> false`. It does read well, though.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
if [a,b,c].any? {|x| x.is_a? String}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but for me, it looks pretty fine, hope its help)

```
def hi(array)
  puts 'hi' if array.any?(String)
end
```

[Enumerable#any?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F)